# springboot jpa entity relation mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, entity

there is 4 table

- BigProject
- SmallProject
- Issue
- Member

1. One BigProject has multiple SmallProject.
2. SmallProject has multiple Issue.
3. One Member can belong to only one BigProject.
4. One Member can belong to multiple SmallProject which belong to Member's BigProject.
5. and Member can create multiple Issue in a SmallProject.

I think relation can be

BigProject [1] : [N] SmallProject

SmallProject [M] : [N] Issue

Issue[N] : [1] Member

SmallProject and Issue looks like M:N relation. so I created relation
table(ProjectIssue)

> SmallProject [N] - [1] ProjectIssue [1] - [N] Issue

**is this correct?**

**And I think Member should include both BigProject and SmallProject, but I don't know how to map the relation.**

my code

```
  //- BigProject -
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bigProject")
    private List<SmallProject> smallProjects;

    //- SmallProject
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "bigproject_no",referencedColumnName = "bigproject_no",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private BigProject bigProject;
```

please help me

Comment: Why do you think there is a m:n relationship between issue and smallProject? This is not directly derived from the original assumptions.

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo MARINO On second thought, SmallProject 1:N Issue relationship is right. Then how define relationship Member with BigProject and SmallProject and Issue?